# Applying functions to each group in a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df<-data.frame(info=c("Lucas sold $3.01","Lucia bought 3.00","Lucas bought $2.5","Lucas sold 
                         $3.01","Lucia bought 3.00","Lucas bought $2.5"),
               number=c("1001","1001","1002","1003","1003","1003"),
               step=c("step 1","step 2","step 1","step 1","step 2","step 3"),
               status=c("ok",NA,NA,"ok",NA,NA))
```

I need to transforme the information that i already have, using diverse functions, but I need to do it grouping the information based in "Number".

For example, I need to group by "number" and then replace the first NA in column "Status" for an "ok", for each group.
Then "status" would be c("ok","ok","ok","ok","ok",NA)

last(which.na(df$status)) would do the trick if I could apply that to each group.

Another function that I need to apply would be to create a new column where I can place a "1", the last time that the word "bought" is in the column "info".

Something like df[max(which(grepl("bought",df$info))]<-"1" would do the trick if I could apply that to each group, but I am not sure about how to do it.

Comment: The use of `group_by()` doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make great use of `dplyr`'s `group_by` syntax here after creating some bespoke functions to do the required tasks:

```
# Replace the last NA element of a vector with 'ok'
replace_first_na <- function(x) {

  # Coerce to character to catch potential issues
  x <- as.character(x)

  # Get the position of the first NA
  first_na <- which(is.na(x))[1]

  # Replace the element in that position with 'ok'
  x[first_na] <- "ok"

  x

}

# Get the last element containing the word 'bought'
last_bought_flag <- function(x) {
  
  # Prepare the output
  out <- rep(0, length(x))
  
  # Get the position of the last string to contain 'bought'
  last_bought <- max(which(grepl("bought", x)))
  
  # Replace the element in that position with `1`
  out[last_bought] <- 1

  # Return the output
  out

}

df %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 

  # Apply grouping by `number`
  group_by(number) %>% 
  
  # Replace the first `NA` with 'ok' in the `status` column
  mutate(status = replace_first_na(status)) %>%
  
  # Get a flag column indicating the last 'bought' item for each group
  mutate(last_bought = last_bought_flag(info)) %>%
  
  # Remove grouping
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Sorry, I need to add a condition to solve it.
 What if I would need to filter the function that you created, "last_bought_flag", based on a different column. For example, if I would need the last one bought that is also "Step 1" in "step" column.

Comment: You could probably either use a `mutate()` or `filter()` for this step. I'd recommend looking through chapter 5 of R For Data Science if you're generally unfamiliar with `dplyr`. As this question seems unrelated to the original one, could you consider accepting my answer above?
https://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html